# Different size images in grid

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for some advice on how to approach creating a grid like the picture included. The images are going to be of different sizes.

It will be included in a wordpress theme that when images are uploaded to the specific post type they will display where the pictures are shown.

I was leaning towards a list with different styles for &:nth-of-type() styles.

TIA for any advice, all is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try using something like Masonry (https://masonry.desandro.com/). Great library, very versatile. There are also frameworks that support grids on demand and nested grids, like SusyGrid (https://www.oddbird.net/susy/). I have used this successfully in the past for asymetrical and nested grid layouts.